# CodeIgniter, update stock

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration

i need some help...
I have a problem with codeigniter, i have this code by myself

```
public function venderProduto($id)
{

        $data=array('id_venda' => null,
        'id_cliente' => $id_cliente,
         'medicamento' => $medicamento,
         'quantidade' => $quantidade,
        'preco' => $preco);

    $this->db->where('id_venda', $id);
    $this->db->select('produto.stock,vendas.quantidade');
    $this->db->insert('vendas', $data);
    $this->db->update('stock-quantidade');
}
```

I need to upgrade the stock of my product that is on the table products(produtos) when I insert a sale on my table sales(vendas), want to take the amount that will see the stock...
Someone help me pls...

Comment: you are making some very basic mistakes. if you are a student then work through the tutorial in the codeigniter manual first. if this is for your business then hire someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your mixing up your queries.  One needs to be completed and then the second can be performed.

If I understand you correctly you want to insert a record into the sales table and then update the products table.

Function does not show how values for id_cliente, medicamento, quantidade, and preco are getting into function.  They would either need to be set as function parameters or supplied as GET or POST vars.

```
public function venderProduto($id, $id_cliente, $medicamento, $quantidade, $preco)
{
        $data = array('id_venda' => null,
        'id_cliente' => $id_cliente,
         'medicamento' => $medicamento,
         'quantidade' => $quantidade,
        'preco' => $preco);

    $this->db->insert('vendas', $data);
    //test to make sure that insert was successful
    if ($this->db->insert_id())
    {
        //get existing stock quantity
        $this->db->select('stock-quantidade');
        $this->db->where('id_venda', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('produtos');
        $row = $query->row();
        $quantity_in_stock = $row->stock-quantidade;

        //I am assuming that $quantidade is the quantity of the order
        $new_quantity_in_stock = $quantity_in_stock - $quantidade;

        //update products table
        $this->db->where('id_venda', $id);
        $this->db->update('produtos', array('stock-quantidade' => $new_quantity_in_stock ));
    }
}
```

The above may or may not work exactly as shown but this IS the logic and order you should use.  If you have trouble you need to post any error messages you receive.

So the order of this is:

1. insert sale.
2. test to make sure insert was successful.
3. get existing quantity of stock.
4. Subtract order quantity from stock quantity.
5. Update stock quantity.

Comment: Didn't work, i need to insert a sale on table sales and update the stock on my table products, my stock on table products is already there, when i do a sale i need to put how much quantity i want and then subtract the quantity i want to stock of that product

Comment: answer updated.  If you get errors then you should post them here.

Comment: i think this code going to work but i got this error in $quantity_in_stock = row->stock-quantidade;

syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)